How to prove wavefront average gradient tilt equals to image centroid displacement?
It is well know that wavefront average tilt equals to image centroid displacement, but how to prove it?
For simplicity, lets say we have a random wavefront $\frac{1}{k}\phi(x)$, and $-r<x<r$. According to Fraunhofer diffraction, light field on image plane is:
$$E(u)=\int_{-r}^{r}\exp(i\phi(x))\exp(-i2\pi ux)\mathrm{d}x$$
and image intensity will be $|E(u)|^2$.
The image centroid displacement will be:
$$\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u|E(u)|^2\mathrm{d}u}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|E(u)|^2\mathrm{d}u}. \tag{1}$$
On the other hand, average wavefront tilt is
$$\frac{\frac{1}{k}\int_{-r}^{r}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x}{\int_{-r}^{r}\mathrm{d}x}. \tag{2}$$
My problem is to prove (1)=(2). I have tried, but failed.

This is a homework question.

@ Ritzthephysibeast  can you show me any articles about this? i know its easily proven in geometric optics, but how to prove it in wave optics?

In geometric optics, the image is where rays intersect. If rays shift, the image shifts. In wave optics, the image is where a wavefront converges to a point. If the wavefront tilts, the image shifts. You might consider that rays are perpendicular to the wavefront.

@mmesser314 i need mathmatical prove, actually there are many ways of discribing wavefront tilt, for example, avrage wavefront gradient and zernike tilt, they are essentially different, but which one correspond with image centroid.
